# Spring bcrypt blank password

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, bcrypt

I'm using Spring Boot webapp with Spring Security. Passwords of my users are stored in my DB after encoding with bcrypt. With some users if I try to login with correct username and blank password (empty string) authentication process not throw exception 401 but return me user as logged in. How is it possible?

---

This is a part of my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final String REMEMBER_ME_KEY = "rememberme_key";
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private RestUnauthorizedEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler restAccessDeniedHandler;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler restAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler restAuthenticationFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bcryptEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new AuthenticationTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SwitchUserFilter switchUserFilter() {
        SwitchUserFilter filter = new SwitchUserFilter();
        filter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        filter.setUsernameParameter("login");
        filter.setSwitchUserUrl("/switch_user");
        filter.setExitUserUrl("/switch_user_exit");
        filter.setTargetUrl("http://xxxxx.xxxxx.it/resource/api/users/me");
        filter.setSwitchFailureUrl("http://xxxxx.xxxxxx.it/resource/version");

        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/switch_user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "GOD")
                .antMatchers("/switch_user_exit").hasRole("PREVIOUS_ADMINISTRATOR")
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/version").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ms3/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/form/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/extapi/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .accessDeniedHandler(restAccessDeniedHandler)
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                .successHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(restAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll().and().rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
                .key(REMEMBER_ME_KEY)
                .and().addFilterAfter(switchUserFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);

        http
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bcryptEncoder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you even using your own authentiation provider?! Just add `.passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())` after the `userDetailsService`. You also have a `authenticationTokenFilterBean` what does that do? That executed before the other filters you use.

Comment: The problem actually is that you have multiple providers (due to the hack that you added your own) which is only consulted for a second pass. I suspect that, due to your configuration, the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` is actually granting access. Instead of hacking, configure your setup correctly (asm entioned in my first comment).

Comment: @M.Deinum I've changed my code in question without authentiation provider. I've `authenticationTokenFilterBean` to generate a token in the way of JWT auth. I need this because I must use spring security switchFilter. This filter works only with session but I've implemented before my rest controller to use JWT security.

Comment: You changed it with what result? Also please add your full configuration (security wise including the annotations) also specify which spring boot / security versions you are using. The code clearly states that if the values differ in length or are empty it should return false so something else must be granting access.

Comment: No the result is the same. I'm using SpringBoot 1.3.3_RELEASE and SpringSecurity 4.0.3_RELEASE. I put all WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter code in question

Comment: You have quite some customized code in there (just wanted to check if you are overriding the spring boot config correctly). I also wonder why are you configuring the `AuthenticationManager` twice. You should only need the global one in your case. There is also Remember Me functionality make sure you aren't passing tokens around and that you are actually correctly logged out.

Comment: I've remove `AuthenticationManager` and I leave only global config one. I alse remove remember me functionality but I've the trouble too. I'm using post to test login so I haven't token or something else around

Comment: The fact that you use a POST doesn't matter. If there is something left in the browser that is added to your request. Enable debug logging for `org.springframework.security` and see what is happening. There is something that is granting access, probably something that uses a token or the likes.